# Manually lock for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, locking, atomic, consistency

I have these operations:

1. Find a doc from collection.
2. Manipulate doc.prop base on it's current value, which "prop" is a string.
3. Update doc back to collection.

So in this case, I have to make sure these operations are atomic, because updating doc.prop must base on the current value.

Here are two approaches:
1. Add "valueKey"(Number) property in doc, make sure valueKey is matched when updating doc. Increase valueKey after updated. If valueKey is not matched, mark this update as failure and retry again.
2. Use "fsyncLock" provided by MongoDB to lock the whole mongod instance, during the operations.

The 1st approach I mentioned above is well, but when facing huge volume of these operations at the same time, the "failure" and "retry" would be frequent.

The 2nd approach, which I haven't tried, I think it is for backing up database and is not good in this case.

So I'm wondering is there any other efficient approach?

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is called an [optimistic lock](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/optimisticOfflineLock.html). Optimistic locks assume that the probability of collision is low, otherwise, as you already pointed out, there are a lot of retries. Those retries can also be destructive - if a text is edited, it might make sense to merge the edits, but it hardly ever makes sense for a phone number.

Locking the entire database is an extreme form of a pessimistic (offline) lock, where the concurrency of the system is deliberately reduced. However, that has problems because [clients don't know what's going on](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/pessimisticOfflineLock.html) - their edits will simply fail which is worst-of-a-kind user experience.

So pessimistic locks really only make sense if clients have a chance of actually *knowing* that something is locked. For instance, you'd somehow need to inform the user that it's not possible to edit the item she wants to edit, because someone else is already in edit-mode for that item. This also has problems, especially if another user left the screen and is blocking all other users.

If you wanted to go for a pessimistic lock, however, that should absolutely never be implemented by something like a global database lock: simply lock the item itself and implement the business logic for the locking in your code.

Morale: This isn't a technology problem, it's a logical problem. Google Docs demonstrates one way to allow concurrent editing of multiple users, but it's hard to implement, has limited use in other types of applications and is still deemed annoying by some users. Git and the likes show another method, where the logic of branches, merging and conflicts is exposed to the user as well, but asynchronously (multi-version concurrency control).